# PHP multiple SFTP Command

Tags: php, ssh, rsa, sftp

My Data vendor only provides sftp connection for downloading files. The authentication of SFTP is done using SSH-RSA private/public key which is set properly.
I have successfully downloaded the files using SSH with following 2 commands

```
sftp -o PORT=6010 JJEE@XX.160.XX.XX
Connected to JJEE@XX.160.XX.XX
sftp> get /BACKUP/01December2021.zip
```

Now to automate this I thought to use PHP and tried 2 methods.

**METHOD 1**

```
<?php
if (!function_exists("ssh2_connect")) 
    {die("function ssh2_connect doesn't exist");}

$connection = ssh2_connect("XX.160.XX.XX","6010",array('hostkey'=>'ssh-rsa'),array());
$connect=ssh2_auth_pubkey_file($connection,'JJEE','/location/id_rsa.pub','/location/id_rsa','');

if ($connect)
    {echo "\n Public Key Authentication Successful <br/>";}
else
    {echo "\n Public Key Authentication failed <br/>";}
?>
```

This is a simple script which is failing with `Public Key Authentication failed`  error and PHP Warning `PHP Warning:  ssh2_auth_pubkey_file(): Authentication failed for JPL_EOD using public key`. I can confirm my `id_rsa.pub` and `id_rsa` permissions are correct.

Since my vendor has only provided me sftp details I think I am unable to create ssh connection through `ssh2_connect`.

I found many suggestion for [phpseclib](https://phpseclib.com/) but I do not want to use 3rd party library just for 2 line of codes.
I decided to use 2nd method as below.

**METHOD 2**

```
<?php
passthru('sftp -o PORT=6010 JJEE@XX.160.XX.XX && get /BACKUP/01December2021.zip');
?>
```

When opened from terminal

```
php /location-to-script/method-2.php
```

I can see that `Connected to JJEE@XX.160.XX.XX` is shown however the second command I think is going as ssh command and not sftp command thus it fails !

My doubt is

1. How to send the second command as sftp command after login to download the file
2. How to send multiple sftp command in continuation if need be
3. Any other better suggestion ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: *"Since my vendor has only provided me sftp details I think I am unable to create ssh connection through ssh2_connect."* – SFTP is an SSH subsystem. There's always an SSH connection under the SFTP. Are you sure the `ssh2_auth_pubkey_file` does not issue any PHP error/warning/hint? + Please post consistent examples. Your `sftp` code shows `JJEE`, while your PHP code shows `my-server-user`.

Comment: Have edited with error details now. I do understand that *There's always an SSH connection under the SFTP* however my vendor replied with statement like *As per our internal policy, ssh is not allowed* that is why I switched to 2nd method

Comment: That's a common misconception. They for sure mean *"ssh **shell access** is not allowed"*. If SSH wasn't allowed, SFTP won't be too. In other words, if OpenSSH `sftp` works, the PHP `ssh2_connect` must work too (except for some incompatibilities or version problems). + Post output of `sftp -vvv -o PORT=6010 JJEE@XX.160.XX.XX` + Btw the port argument of `ssh2_connect` should be an integer, not a string (though it's probably not a problem).

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to download in 1 line of syntax, which I did not know before, because of Key-pair login this did not required any password !

I finally used

`passthru('sftp -o PORT=6010 JJEE@XX.160.XX.XX:/BACKUP/01December2021.zip',$result);`

This is not an exact answer but it did temporarily solve the issue.